# extension of plurisubharmonic functions across complex hypersurfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be an open set and let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Moreover, assume that $f$ is smooth on the complement of a complex hypersurface $Z \subset U$ and satisfies $i \partial \bar{\partial} f > 0$ on $U \setminus Z$.

Question: Is $f$ plurisubharmonic on $U$?

I would really appreciate a reference for this result (which I beleive is true).

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference, [Demailly, Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry, Theorem 5.24](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf).

The point is that $Z$ is pluripolar, meaning that there is a psh function which identically $-\infty$ on $Z$, for example $\log |g|$ where $g$ is a defining holomorphic function for $Z$. One can check that $f_{\epsilon} =f + \epsilon g$ is psh for every $\epsilon>0$ and $f_{\epsilon} \to f$ in $L^1_{loc}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.